# older browsers won't recognize ` in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser, zurb-foundation

I'm building a calculator with Foundation range slider. It's working fine in Safari 9, latest Chrome and Firefox for both Mac and Windows, Edge 14. But it doesn't work in Safari 8 or IE 11. In Safari 8, I see an error **SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`'**
The javascript code looks like this:

```
Foundation.Move(moveTime, $hndl, function() {
  //adjusting the left/top property of the handle, based on the percentage calculated above
  $hndl.css(lOrT, `${movement}%`);

  if (!_this.options.doubleSided) {
    //if single-handled, a simple method to expand the fill bar
    _this.$fill.css(hOrW, `${pctOfBar * 100}%`);
  } else {
    //otherwise, use the css object we created above
    _this.$fill.css(css);
  }
});
```

If I change ` to ', it doesn't work in any browser. Anyone has any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Of course they won't, ES2015 doesn't work in old browsers, it hardly works reliably in new browsers, and templating strings is an ES2015 feature.

Comment: Use Babel to transpile your JavaScript https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to support older browsers, your only real choice is to not use template literals.  It is a relatively new feature in JavaScript, and so older browsers will not understand how to interpret it.

Here it the link to the documentation which shows it's support:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

You can always to back to the "old fashioned way":

this

```
 `${movement}%`
```

becomes this:

```
 movement + "%"
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I had to do some customization on the sliders so I basically copied the function from Foundation's slider plugin. I never used template literals myself before. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad I could help!